# How to fix the alignment of my sub-menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, alignment

I'm trying to perfect a navigation bar and so far the only thing wrong is the alignment is the drop down menu. Is there anyway to position it relative to the td it is in without re-doing all of my code? If not how would I go about lowering the sub-menu from the menu.

**Here is my CSS**

```
        ul.nav{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style: ;

    }

    ul li.nav{
    float: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    background:transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
     }

     ul li.nav:hover{
    float: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
     }

    ul li.nav2{
    float: left;
        width: 70%;
        text-align: left;
    background:#313131;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;

     }


    ul li a{

        display: block;
        padding: 0px 0px;
    color: white;
        background:#313131;
        text-decoration: none ;

    }
    ul li a.nav:hover{

    text-align: left;
        color: white;
        background:transparent;

    }
    ul li ul.nav{

    width: 25%;
    display: none ;

    }
    ul li.nav:hover ul{
    float: center;
    opacity: .87;
    position: absolute;
        display: block; /* display the dropdown */


    }

    td.nav:hover{
    background-color:#703f70;
    color: #703f70;
    }

    a:link {
        color: white;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    a:hover {

        color: #5be5e5 ;
        background-color: #703f70;
    }

    a.amber:hover {
    color: ;
        background-color: transparent ;
    }

input { 
font: 13.5pt arial; 
color: #5be5e5; 
margin: 0px; 
padding-top: 5px; 
padding-left: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
display: ; 
background: #703f70; 
border-color: #b266b2;
font-weight:bold;
}

input:hover {
color: #5be5e5;
background: #b266b2;
border-color: #703f70;
}

</style>
```

**Here is my HTML**

```
<table width="95%"   align="center" valign="bottom"
<tr>

<td width="11%" bgcolor="#313131">
</td>

<td class="nav" bordercolor="#313131" bgcolor="#313131" align="center" valign="bottom" width="12.25%">
<ul class="nav"><li class="nav">
<a href="homepage.html"><font size="3"><b>
<img src="graphics/homeicon1.png" width="25" height="25">
<br>
Home Page
</b></font></a>
</li></ul>
</td>   

<td class="nav" bordercolor="#313131" bgcolor="#313131" align="center" valign="bottom" height="1" width="12.25%">
<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav"><a href="contentpage.html"> <img src="graphics/contenticon1.PNG" width="20" height="25"> <br> <font size="3"><b> <img src="graphics/dropdownarrowlefticon1.PNG" width="10" height="10"> Content Page <img src="graphics/dropdownarrowrighticon1.PNG" width="10" height="10"> </b></font> </a>
    <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav2"><a href="interactivewebsitespage.html"><font size="5"><b> <img src="graphics/interactiveicon1.png" width="20" height="20"> Interactive </b></font></a></li>
    <li class="nav2"><a href="noninteractivewebsitespage.html"><font size="5"><b> <img src="graphics/noninteractiveicon1.png" width="20" height="20"> Noninteractive </b></font></a></li>
    <li class="nav2"><a href="videogamespage.html"><font size="5"><b> <img src="graphics/videogamesicon1.png" width="20" height="15"> Video Games</b></font></a></li>
    <li class="nav2"><a href="youtubevideospage.html"><font size="5"><b> <img src="graphics/youtubevideosicon1.png" width="20" height="20"> Youtube Videos</b></font></a></li>
</li class="nav">             
</ul class="nav">
</td>        

<td class="nav" bordercolor="#313131" bgcolor="#313131" align="center" valign="bottom" width="12.25%">
<ul class="nav">
<li class="nav">
<a href="infopage.html"><font size="3"><b> 
<img src="graphics/infoicon1.PNG" width="25" height="25"> 
<br> 
Info Page 
</b></font></a>          
</li></ul>
</td>

<td class="nav" bordercolor="#313131" bgcolor="#313131" align="center"valign="bottom" width="12.25%">   
<ul class="nav"><li class="nav">
<a href="pollpage.html"><font size="3"><b>
<img src="graphics/pollicon1.PNG" width="25" height="25">
<br>
Poll Page
</li></ul>
</b></font></a></li>
</td>

<td width="11%" bgcolor="#313131">
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

**Here is a live example**

http://jsfiddle.net/B7a5f/

The live example is a little messed up of course but for the most part the concern is that its position is too far to the right and higher up than I like it.

Comment: Please don't do layout with tables...it's so 1980's.

Comment: @Paulie_D is all right.  Let use divs.

Comment: You can see my own test http://trimax.hol.es/menus-css/menu_desplegable_horizontal.html

Comment: dude, use html and css. it can be done in 10lines

Comment: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu Hope this link will be useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   ul.nav{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table-cell;
        padding: 0px;
        margin:0;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: @ Cristian Rubini it did fix the problem but is there anyway to keep the text aligned center?

Comment: `ul.nav{
     text-decoration: none;
     display: table-cell;
            padding: 0px;
            list-style: ;
            margin:0;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
        }`

`ul li.nav{
     float: left;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
     background:transparent;
     text-decoration: none;
     list-style-type: none;
         }`

Comment: that definitely did it though now the size of the parent increased. If you want to just tell me what to look at specifically to fix it that will be fine. Sorry for bothering you and thanks for your help.